# Binding to Textbox property is not Updating when I open My save file

Tags: c#, wpf, properties

I am saving a file with my own extension which it is just XML. When I open the file I parse the data and assign it to my Public property which assigns it to my private field. I have stepped through the code and can see that all the assignments are being made but cannot figure out why the *UI* is not being updated. I have `INotifyPropertyChanged` and I am calling `OnPropertyChanged`. I posted only the relevant parts of the code.

Any help is appreciated thanks.

```
 <TextBox Name="PersonsName" Width="150" Height="20" 
             Text="{Binding Path=PersonName, Mode=TwoWay,        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50, 30, 0, 0"
             IsEnabled="{Binding SetState, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

 public string PersonName
    {
        get { return _personName; }
        set
        {
            _personName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("PersonName");
        }
    } 

   public static void ParseSavedConfigurationFromDoc(XDocument doc, ButtonLockViewModel person)
    {
        XElement generalElement = doc.Element("SavedPerson");

        person.PersonName = generalElement.Attribute("Name").Value;
        person.PersonAge = generalElement.Attribute("Age").Value;

    } 

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Damm question, but you set the data context of your view right?
A lot of people have a viewm odel inside this a person model. the view hast the data context of the view model so the binding hast to be Path=Person.PersonName

Comment: Yeah, looks okay to me... so some stupid questions. Data Context okay?  You did add `public partial class YourClass: Window, INotifyPropertyChanged`, right?  Maybe show your OnPropertyChanged?

Comment: The Data context should be ok I will look at it again. Yes on the second set of questions. I will post the OnpropertyChanged.

Comment: It was in my open save file command. I changed the datacontext without realizing it.

Comment: private void OpenFileDialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = sender as Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog;
            XDocument doc = OpenSavedXmlConfiguration(openFileDialog1.FileNames[0]);
            ButtonLockViewModel personConfig = new ButtonLockViewModel();

            XmlFileGenerator.ParseSavedConfigurationFromDoc(doc, this);
        }